# Getting "real" locale used by MacOS

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I've made a MacOS app where the user can select the language he wants inside the app.

To set a localized title in a button I do this:

```
NSLocalizedString("CONTEXT_MENU_OPT_QUIT", bundle: myClass.localeBundle, comment: "Context menu option");
```

And I run this code at start-up to set `localeBundle`:

```
    func getLocale() -> String {
        let availableLanguages: [String] = Bundle.main.localizations;
        var locale: String = userDefaults!.string(forKey: "locale") ?? "";

        if (locale.isEmpty) {
            let preferredLocale: String = Locale.preferredLanguages.first!;

            if (availableLanguages.contains(preferredLocale) == false) {
                locale = "en";
            }
        }
        return locale;
    }

    func loadLocale() {
        let currentLocale: String = self.getLocale();
        var bundlePath: String;

        bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: currentLocale, ofType: "lproj")!;
        myClass.localeBundle = Bundle.init(path: bundlePath)!;
    }
```

This works for most people, but if you have the system language set differently than the expected region, this will fail. Eg.:

Language is Portuguese, region is set to Russia: `Locale.preferredLanguages.first!` will return `pt-RU`

Considering I only have translations for `pt-PT` and `pt-BR` the code I have will default to "en", because "pt-RU" doesn't exist.

How do I get `pt-PT` and `pt-BR` independently of the user's region?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user's setting for preferred language (as set in System Preferences) is stored in user defaults under the key "AppleLanguages". It's an array of language identifier strings (like "pt-BR").

The user's setting is in the global domain but, as with all user defaults, you can override that in more local domains. In particular, you can set it in the application domain to affect just your app.

So, I think you should just store an array with the identifier for the language chosen by the user for your app under the "AppleLanguages" key and then let the system do its thing. You should not try to reproduce the resource search algorithm yourself.

If you want to keep using your technique, you can use the [localization properties and methods](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle#1652622) of `Bundle` to pick one of the actual localizations available in a bundle according to a list of preferred ones. That is, don't query the `localizations` and then check if it contains your locale identifier; use `preferredLocalizations(from:forPreferences:)` to do the search for you. It likely uses a more sophisticated algorithm. Also, keep in mind the distinction between locale and language and, especially, locale IDs vs language IDs. The represent different things and have different forms, but you seem to be using them interchangeably.

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something, I've set a new VM with the main language set as French and the region to Russia. Added a couple more languages too.

`UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AppleLanguages")` returned this: `["fr-RU", "pt-RU", "en-RU"]` and `Bundle.preferredLocalizations(from: UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AppleLanguages") as! [String])` returned this: `fr-RU`. I expected it to return `fr` as that's the closest locale I have in the bundle

Comment: `Bundle.preferredLocalizations(from:)` is a class method. That is, it's not specific to any particular bundle, not even the main bundle. It's taking the list of localizations you provide and picking the one that's closest to the user preferences. Since you're just passing the user preferences, there's no reason for it to do anything but return the first. If you want to abide by the user preferences, you can just check `Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations`. If you want to use custom internal preferences, you would use `Bundle.preferredLocalizations(from:… forPreferences:…)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ken. Very clear explanation.
I completely missed it was a class method, I was thinking it was checking the main bundle.